# How can i Select from two different tables in one code?

Tags: c#

I'm using two times sqlreader cause i have to select from two different tables how can i do this with one code?Here is my code:

First Sqlreader:

```
 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name from Customers where name = '"+textview2.Text+"'", con);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            textview1.Text = (sqlReader["Name"].ToString());


        }
        sqlReader.Close();
```

Second Read:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Mobile from Informations where Mobile = '"+textview3.Text+"'", con);
        SqlDataReader sqlReader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlReader2.Read())
        {
            textview4.Text = (sqlReader2["Mobile"].ToString());
        }

        sqlReader2.Close();
```

I want to create one code instead of two.

Comment: create procedure , you can union results also

Comment: This was an example i use ex. two columns from first read and 3 columns from second.If i will use union i get this error:All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: If there's a relation between `Customers` and `Informations` table, then you can use sql join.

Comment: Curious: why don't you use LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to use parameterized queries. I invite you to search about why this is the mandatory way to build sql queries and drop as soon as possible the use of string concatenations. After that you can join the two commands together and use the [NextResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the SqlDataReader to reach your second data

```
// Both commands text are passed to the same SqlCommand
string cmdText = @"SELECT Name from Customers where name = @name;
                   SELECT Mobile from Informations where Mobile = @mobile";
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

// Set the parameters values....
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textview2.Text
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textview3.Text
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
     // Should be only one record, but to be safe, we need to consume
     // whatever there is in the first result
     while(sqlReader.Read())
         textview1.Text = (sqlReader["Name"].ToString());

     // Move to the second result (if any)
     if(sqlReader.NextResult())
     {
          // Again, we expect only one record with the mobile searched 
          // but we need to consume all the possible data 
         while(sqlReader.Read())
            textview4.Text = (sqlReader["Mobile"].ToString());
     }
}
sqlReader.Close();
```

By the way, you already know the name and the mobile, then why do you execute this code?

Comment: Not sure how this happens. Look at this example on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check if the changes made fix the problem

Comment: Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respondafter a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Is the connection open?

Comment: It is open. Dont worry i will use my first method.

Comment: Well, I can't blame you, but really something odd is at work here, because, if you look at the MSDN example linked, this is more or less the exact code used there. It should work.